# why @use 'base' is not working in SCSS in React?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm trying to use (e.g. $Dark-color:#333) SCSS from my main SCSS file to another SCSS file with the help of @use module.

my main file scss

```
_Style.scss

$Dark-Violet: hsl(256, 26%, 20%);
```

and my other scss file which I'm using this @use module

```
@use 'base';

.firstSection {

    background-color: base.$Dark-Violet;
}
```

showing the below error when I'm using this module.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use 'base';
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\Style\Section.scss 1:1  root stylesheet**
```

how to get off this error? Also, Can it run if I use SCSS module styling in react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```scss
@use 'Style';
.firstSection {
    background-color: Style.$Dark-Violet;
}
```

I mean, your base file seems to be called "_Style.scss" not "_base.scss", am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks! it working but few issues still facing. it is only working when both `"_Style.css"` and other SCSS files are in the same folder. Also, it is not working when I'm using SCSS as a module.

Comment: For this to work in another folder, you either can specify relative path or define resolver or path in the webpack config. Regarding modules, may be probably some other webpack configuration issue, for that probably need another question with details.